# Работа нескольких virtual host на одном доменном имени

Tags: веб-программирование, веб-сервер, dns, virtual, virtual-hosts

Простой вопрос. Если имеется сервер с конкретным IP и привязанным к нему доменным именем (зарегистрированным, например www.homepage.com). То каким образом осуществляется переход по разным virtual host в пределах сервера. Ведь, чтобы попасть на заданный сервер все равно придется обращаться к www.homepage.com. То есть концепция virtual host имеет смысл, только если для одного IP зарегистрировано у регистратора более одного доменного имени. Правильно ли я понимаю. Спасибо

Comment: Не совсем. Сервер может сидеть на разных портах и отдавать разный контент по одному доменному имени. Например, www.homepage.com:80,  www.homepage.com:88,  www.homepage.com:443

Comment: Тогда необходимо указывать при обращении порт явным образом? Разве так делают на практике? В браузере вводить domain_name:port?

Comment: Поддомены тоже никто не отменял: cdn.homepage.com, admin.homepage.com и так далее

Comment: То есть при обращении к любым поддоменам dns сервер будет отдавать один и тот же IP?

Comment: Да, если добавить A/AAAA-запись со звёздочкой (что автоматически охватит все поддомены третьего уровня)

Comment: Получается, если запросить у любого сайта домен 3-его уровня, например для сайта www.site.com выполнить запрос any_name.site.com, то получим IP сервера www.site.com в независимости есть ли там физически  any_name.site.com?

Comment: Не у любого, а у того, где A-запись со звёздочкой есть

Comment: Поясните про звездочку) Речь идет про добавление на сервере регистратора dns?

Comment: Речь идёт про добавление A/AAAA-записи на связанном с доменом DNS-сервере, а где этот DNS-сервер находится — решает уже тот, кто купил домен. Некоторые регистраторы предоставляют бесплатную услугу администрирования DNS в дополнение к купленному домену, но это не обязательно.

Comment: А фраза «есть ли там физически» кстати слегка бессмысленна — попробуйте посетить http://dfbdqkj.andreymal.org и попробуйте набрать любую белиберду вместо dfbdqkj — всё равно будет нормально открываться.

Comment: @and_noob указание порта - вполне нормальная практика. Да, не часто, но делается.